# how can my android app read data from arduino adk?

Tags: arduino, adk

I have an Arduino ADK, NFC Shield, and a Android Tablet. So far, I can already read tags using the NFC shield attached to the Arduino ADK then output the tag to the serial monitor.

Now I need to use the tag in my android app to identify the user whenever his tag will be read by the NFC reader. And also to use that tag (datatype is String) in my other java methods and functions.

**Can anyone recommend a step by step tutorial on how I can do this?**

Ultimately, I want to program my android app so it can also read and use the tag sent from Arduino ADK provided that the android tablet and Arduino ADK are connected without my PC connecting them but just a wire. I just don't know how to program it on Eclipse. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html). It's the documentation from Google detailing how to communicate between the app and the Arduino.